# PRIMARY KEY constraint and AUTO INCREMENT in an Excel file database

Tags: sql, database, vba, excel

I'm using an Excel file as a database, and I would like to set the ID column as primary key, and auto increment the value of this column when a new record is inserted in database.

Comment: Basically, Excel is **NOT** a database and doesn't have these concepts - if you need a database - use one - like SQL Server or MySQL or something like that.

Comment: What about using MS Access even?

Comment: Can you give more details/indications about your proposal @JoshuaRoss ?

Comment: Like they said. However you can simulate a PK auto-increment by doing `=ROW()-1`, assuming row 1 is your header and that you're not deleting rows. But seriously, *Excel is not a database* - it's a formidable hammer, but **not every problem is a nail**!

Answer (score 2):

#### TL:DR;

You can't. Excel is not a database management system.

#### Possible alternative

You can easily copy & paste to/from Excel, or even set up scheduled imports, using MS Access, which ships with most if not all MS Office versions for Windows. This will offer you the DBMS-specific features you are looking for.

Just create a table in Access, leave the first column `ID` as-is then paste/import data in the other columns. The `ID` column already has PK and auto-increment by default.

---

You could also use a more "complete" free DBMS, such as [MS SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx), [MySQL](https://www.mysql.com/) or [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/).

Answer (score 0):

As per above comments Excel isn't the tool to do this, BUT, if you wanted to, you could add a forumla to do this. [Check this post](http://www.thoughtasylum.com/blog/2013/6/29/auto-incrementing-in-excel.html)

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps to create PRIMARY KEY using Excel Custom Validation to Prevent Duplicate Entries in a Excel Cell.

1) Select entire empty column(a column with no input).

2) Go to  DATA >> DATA VALIDATION

3) Choose CUSTOM from Allow Drop down list

4) paste `=COUNTIF($A:$A,A1)=1` in Formula field.

Now, you column is setup with Primary Keys, means each cell beginning from A1 to entire range of A column allows only unique values as shown below.

[image]

So now if you want to put two same value in that excel cell then you got the following error:-

[image]

**EDIT:-** Use Header of excel column to select the row. See Red Circle in below Image, click here to select Whole column in Excel. Then follow from step 2 in above steps

[image]

Comment: I get an error when trying your formula, apparently the syntax is not correct. @Piyush

Comment: How you choose to select column in Excel (use Header of excel column to select the row) See Edit. I tried it in new excel it working. I have Office Professional Plus 2010 version. and make sure that You put the right column name in formula.  if you are choosing Column A then formula has A. Change based on your column name

Answer (score 0):

I can help you only with AUTO INCREMENT ;)

Have a look at the following VBScript code, just run a SELECT to find out the last value for your ID column, then run another SQL command to INSERT new row with (LastValue+1).

```
Dim Conn, RS
Set Conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=""D:/YourFile.xlsx"";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=0;"";" 'Use "IMEX=0" to be able to UPDATE. 
Conn.Open
Set RS = Conn.Execute("SELECT MAX([Id]) AS LastID FROM [Sheet1$A1:E10] ")
Conn.Execute("INSERT INTO [Sheet1$A1:E10] ([Id], [Field1], [FieldN]) VALUES ('" & CStr(Abs(RS("LastID")) + 1) & "', 'Some value', 'Another value')")
RS.Close
Conn.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Set Conn = Nothing
```

Answer (score -2):

It would be great, I guess, if MS-Excel could generate a random number, and fix it on a cell. Like, if I could fix a random number plus the result of the now() formula as a concatenated text, the problem would be solved. I saw some tips to do that on VBA, but not really as the mate asked.